# clang-4.0 generates redundant methods when initializing global variables

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm learning LLVM these days via observing how clang deal with complex situations. I wrote (top level, not in a function):

```
int qaq = 666;
int tat = 233;

auto hh = qaq + tat;
```

And I use the command:

```
clang-4.0 003.cpp -emit-llvm -S -std=c++11
```

And clang generates codes like this:

```
@qaq = global i32 666, align 4
@tat = global i32 233, align 4
@hh = global i32 0, align 4
@llvm.global_ctors = appending global [1 x { i32, void ()*, i8* }] [{ i32, void ()*, i8* } { i32 65535, void ()* @_GLOBAL__sub_I_003.cpp, i8* null }]

; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal void @__cxx_global_var_init() #0 section ".text.startup" {
  %1 = load i32, i32* @qaq, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* @tat, align 4
  %3 = add nsw i32 %1, %2
  store i32 %3, i32* @hh, align 4
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal void @_GLOBAL__sub_I_003.cpp() #0 section ".text.startup" {
  call void @__cxx_global_var_init()
  ret void
}
```

I'm confused with `_GLOBAL__sub_I_003.cpp`: why does clang generate a function that actually only invoke another function (and not doing anything else)? Even both of them have no parameters?

Comment: Also of relevance: keep in mind that this is unoptimized code. LLVM/Clang can be kinda intentionally sloppy due to high confidence in its optimization passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is my interpretation of the logic, I'm not part of the LLVM team.

In order to understand the reasoning behind this, you have to understand a fundamental concept in software engineering: **Complexity creates bugs, and makes testing harder.**

But first, let's make your example a little more interesting:

```
int qaq = 666;
int tat = 233;

auto hh = qaq + tat;
auto ii = qaq - tat;
```

Which leads to:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal void @__cxx_global_var_init() #0 section ".text.startup" !dbg !16 {
  %1 = load i32, i32* @qaq, align 4, !dbg !19
  %2 = load i32, i32* @tat, align 4, !dbg !20
  %3 = add nsw i32 %1, %2, !dbg !21
  store i32 %3, i32* @hh, align 4, !dbg !21
  ret void, !dbg !20
}

; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal void @__cxx_global_var_init.1() #0 section ".text.startup" !dbg !22 {
  %1 = load i32, i32* @qaq, align 4, !dbg !23
  %2 = load i32, i32* @tat, align 4, !dbg !24
  %3 = sub nsw i32 %1, %2, !dbg !25
  store i32 %3, i32* @ii, align 4, !dbg !25
  ret void, !dbg !24
}

; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal void @_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp() #0 section ".text.startup" !dbg !26 {
  call void @__cxx_global_var_init(), !dbg !28
  call void @__cxx_global_var_init.1(), !dbg !29
  ret void
}
```

So we see that CLANG emits a single function for each non-trivial initialization, and calls each of them one after the other in `_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp()`. That makes sense and is sensible, as things are neatly organized this way, and could become a garbled mess in larger/more complicated files otherwise.

Notice how that's the exact same logic that is being applied in your example.

Doing otherwise would imply an algorithm of the type: "if there is a single non-trivial global initialization, then put the code directly in the translation unit's global constructor".

Note the following:

- The current logic handles that case correctly already.
- In optimized code, the end result would be the exact same.

So what would that logic get us, really?

- More branches to test.
- More opportunities to accidentaly insert a bug.
- More code to maintain in the long run.
- Removal of a single function call in the global initialization of some translation units in non-optimized builds.

Keeping things the way they are is just the right decision.

Comment: Thank you! I've just tested it and it behaves exactly as you said. But why 'noinline' for the GLOBAL__sub_I_example? This function is only used once.

Comment: It "looks" like declaration-less functions always have that tag for semantic reasons: [see source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/72ee108137acea74ea7d3c05362bb06d25637cc2/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp#L934)